# How to have different markdownlint rules for CHANGELOG.md files

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown, changelog

In VS Code, I use markdownlint for my markdown files.  I like the rules that it imposes except for my CHANGELOG.md file (see [keepachangelog.com](https://keepachangelog.com)).

Is there a way to have one set of rules for most of my markdown files and another set for the change log?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use custom markdownlint configuration for a file by using the following syntax:

```
<!-- markdownlint-configure-file { options.config JSON } -->
```

For example, to set line length of the `CHANGELOG.md` file to 90, add the following to it:

```
<!-- markdownlint-configure-file { "MD013": { "line_length": 90 } } -->
```

For more details, see the markdownlint's [Configuration documentation](https://github.com/DavidAnson/markdownlint#configuration).